# NoMethodError in OrdersController#populate Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#populate

undefined method `completed?' for nil:NilClass
```

Gets the above error when i click checkout...any idea.

**Full trace**

```
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
spree_core (0.70.3) app/models/line_item.rb:73:in `update_inventory'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:16:in `insert_record'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:128:in `concat'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:337:in `add_to_target'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:127:in `concat'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:125:in `each'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:125:in `concat'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:147:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:124:in `concat'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:118:in `<<'
spree_core (0.70.3) app/models/order.rb:216:in `add_variant'
spree_core (0.70.3) app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:49:in `populate'
spree_core (0.70.3) app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:47:in `each'
spree_core (0.70.3) app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:47:in `populate'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:452:in `_run__1106774758__process_action__1039901831__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
spree_core (0.70.3) lib/redirect_legacy_product_url.rb:10:in `call'
spree_core (0.70.3) lib/middleware/seo_assist.rb:23:in `call'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:54 railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:49 script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Comment: Edit your question and paste in the populate method in your orders_controller. Looks like you have an instance variable thats empty

Comment: This happens when the line item doesn't link to an order. Could you please provide steps to reproduce that?

Comment: Actually, It works all well on local machine...rails 3.1.1, ruby 1.8.7 with same gemfile, i'm trying to run it on hostgator VPS, it gives undefined method `completed?' for nil:NilClass ... not able to trace it at all...

Comment: I had to override order.rb file where the error disappears if i comment "self.line_items << current_item " ... but it doesn;t add any product to the cart...

Comment: Now, the issue is somewhere in orders_controller.rb, If i comment @order.add_variant, it redirects to cart_path without added any product to cart params[:variants].each do |variant_id, quantity|
      quantity = quantity.to_i
  #   @order.add_variant(Variant.find(variant_id), quantity) if quantity > 0
    end if params[:variants]

Answer (score 0):

gem 'mysql2' in Gemfile and bundle install worked...